# Travis CI Android: Error: Could not access the Package Manager

Tags: android, gradle, build, travis-ci

I'm trying to use Travis CI in an Android repo and it's giving me a headache.

This is my .travis.yml file

```
sudo: required
jdk: oraclejdk8
language: android
android:
  components:
    # Uncomment the lines below if you want to
    # use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
    # - tools
    # - platform-tools

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - tools
    - build-tools-26.0.2
    - platform-tools
    - tools

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-25

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-android-support
    - addon-google_apis-google-25

    # Specify at least one system image,
    # if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-25
env:
  global:
    - API=25 # Android API level 25 by default
    - TAG=google_apis # Google APIs by default, alternatively use default
    - ABI=armeabi-v7a # ARM ABI v7a by default
    - QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none # Disable emulator audio to avoid warning
    #- ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-26.1.1 # Depends on the cookbooks version used in the VM
    - TOOLS=${ANDROID_HOME}/tools # PATH order matters, exists more than one emulator script
    - PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${TOOLS}:${TOOLS}/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=20 # minutes (2 minutes by default)

before_install:
  - export EMULATOR="system-images;android-${API};${TAG};${ABI}" # Used to install/create emulator
  - echo 'count=0' > /home/travis/.android/repositories.cfg # Avoid warning
  - cd ./GimnasIO
  - chmod +x gradlew

install:
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "tools"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-25" # Latest platform required by SDK tools
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-${API}" # Android platform required by emulator
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.2"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "$EMULATOR" # Install emulator system image
  # Create and start emulator
  - echo no | avdmanager create avd -n acib -k "$EMULATOR" -f --abi "$ABI" --tag "$TAG"
  - emulator -avd acib -engine classic -no-window -verbose -qemu -m 512 &

before_script:
  # Wait for emulator fully-booted and disable animations
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
  - ./gradlew build connectedCheck

after_script:
  - cat ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/*/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/*
```

I have the ANDROID_HOME line commented because it was giving me an error and works fine without it apparently.

So, I looked up the problem and found that adding "android-wait-for-emulator" should work fine, but it doesn't. This is the first of the errors:

```
Unable to install /home/travis/build/.../app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure (Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?)
```

Any idea why this keeps happening?

Comment: @dani1495, I wrote that lines, probably outdated, and the location/version changed. Use `ls` command to find the new `ANDROID_HOME` path and comment out it, or comment `TOOLS` and `PATH` lines because depend on `ANDROID_HOME`.